# for statement (looping calculation priority)*not sure if this is the correct term

Tags: python, loops

```
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
} 

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}
total = 0 

for item in prices:
    a=prices[item]*stock[item]
    total=total+a
    print total
```

so here is my code, i intentionally wrote the print total within the for statement, so it print out the order of calculation for me and the number goes like this 48.0
93.0 117.0 117.0, so after the basic calculation the first value that the statement churns out is the total of orange the second is the total of pear the third is the banana and the last is the apple

now i am curious under what principle is this precedence of calculation carried out cause it seems to me that it started with the largest number in dic_stock and calculated in a descending manner, i do aware this is just a superficial observation,there must be a reason why computer did this

can anyone tell me why :)

Comment: Bananas are expensive ;/

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are not ordered. So, the ordering in which you get the key-value pair is not fixed. 
If you need to define insertion order on your dict, you need to use [collections.`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: thanks !  it bugged me for a while i was tried so hard to looking for patterns! it is tough to be a aspie :(  but thanks!